# avoid duplicate frames in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, export, image-processing, framerate, opencv

I have a video.mp4 which I need to convert losslessly into a sequence of images.
I used
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 $filename%05d.tiff`
but I get a lot (thousands) of duplicated frames. What are they? is it possible to avoid that ffmpeg exports them? I had to stop the operation because it was taking forever.

---

The video file:
`codec`: H265 – MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
`Encoder`: Lavf58.29.100
`FPS`: 70.476432
`resolution`: 1824 x 1216
`Duration`: 0m31s

---

Full output from ffmpeg (I use Linux):

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 $filename%05d.tiff

ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)

  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared

  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:31.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 746 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1824x1216, 741 kb/s, 70.48 fps, 1k tbr, 90k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> tiff (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to '%05d.tiff':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: tiff, yuv420p(progressive), 1824x1216, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k fps, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                
      handler_name    : VideoHandler                                                                                                                                                         
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]                                                                                                                                                         
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 tiff                                                                                                                                                  
More than 1000 frames duplicatedN/A time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=N/A dup=976 drop=0 speed=0.0308x                                                                                                
More than 10000 frames duplicated/A time=00:00:10.74 bitrate=N/A dup=9989 drop=0 speed=0.0265x                                                                                               
frame=17673 fps= 26 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:17.67 bitrate=N/A dup=16428 drop=0 speed=0.0262x
```

---

After trying different options, I found 3 alternatives that achieve the same results. I give details below.

**Option 1** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938111/removing-duplicate-frames-with-ffmpeg))
**Comment**: it uses variable frame-rate mode.
**Command**: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -vsync vfr $filename%05d.tiff`
**Result**: it works. The video is exported as 2245 TIFF images (~6.2GB) and no messages about duplicate frames.

**Option 2** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964070/removing-duplicate-frames))
**Comment**: it retimes the frames using the `setpts` filter.
**Command**: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/24/TB -vsync vfr $filename%05d.tiff`
**Result**: it works. The video is exported as 2245 TIFF images (~6.2GB) and no messages about duplicate frames. According to the question in the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964070/removing-duplicate-frames), the resulting framerate is 24 FPS (as requested by the OP), but this is not what I need. I need to respect the FPS of the original video (if possible).

**Option 3** ([source](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36418/frame-rate-vs-extracted-frames/))
**Comment**: This keeps 1:1 correspondence between input and output frames.
**Command**: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vsync passthrough $filename%05d.tiff`
**Result**: it works. The video is exported as 2246 TIFF images (~6.2GB) and no messages about duplicate frames.

The strange thing (to me anyway) is that all 3 options produce exactly the same TIFF files, each one with a size of 2.8 MiB (I even compared a couple of random pairs by contents, and the files are actually identical, except that option 3 generates 1 more file than options 1 and 2).

Comment: there are many similar questions on stack overflow, have you tried some of the answers? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088517/remove-sequentially-duplicate-frames-when-using-ffmpeg)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938111/removing-duplicate-frames-with-ffmpeg)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977300/ffmpeg-more-than-1000-frames-duplicated-and-input-height-doesnt-match)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964070/removing-duplicate-frames)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966394/how-to-simply-remove-duplicate-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've seen those posts and I thought they applied to video-to-video but after trying some more tests I was able to apply some of those things to my case. I will edit the original question.

Comment: By the way I used superuser and video because I was suggested that Sack Overflow is rather for software developers and my question did not fit there...  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @terauser this is more or less the correct spot, although https://video.stackexchange.com could be even better. There are many old questions like this on SO because admins didn't think that moving them to more proper sites when changing rules would be a good idea ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ One of the biggest flaws of StackExchange, IMO, as people see similar questions there and ask there just to be redirected to other sites, sometimes in a rude way.